# Moving objects to a location

Tags: transforms, origin

This is probably a simple thing I'm just overlooking.  When I move an object, it moves the amount I enter.  I would like it to move TO the location I enter instead.  What I need is the plane representing the floor of my model to move to the zero location of the Y axis.  When I enter G, Y, 0 it goes nowhere, of course.  When I enter G, Y, 1 it moves 1 from where it started.  How can I get to move to the location I specify?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: if you open the 3D view right panel (press N) > Item tab, you can use the Location values and press what you want, is it what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, that helped a lot.  Thank you!!